# Group level permissions in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, permissions, django-views

I have a list of custom permissions in the Permission model, a User model and a Group model. I have different set of permissions(from the Permission model) defined for each group. Each user belongs to a particular group. I want to include a permission check in my website such that whenever a user logs in and tries to go to a view, the back-end checks if the user has the permission to enter the particular view. How to implement this in my website?
Note: I am not using django REST framework.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for creating a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user has all the permissions assigned to them directly as well as those assigned to any group that they are a member of.

To restrict access to a view based on Django permissions you can:

- use the permission decorator:
  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator
- wrap the view function (e.g. in urls.py) with `user_passes_test()` with a test that checks for the permission: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test
- or check explicitly with `user.has_perm()` (same page as the above links, just read all of it)